# How to pass list values to the jqplot to get the stacked bar chart

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, list, jqplot

I am trying draw a stacked bar chart but bar itsels is not shown. Dont know why?.
let me explain what I am doing. I have stored  values in 3 columns of the  database  then using list(collections) i am able to display it on my table using jsp. Now i have written the code to generate stacked bar chart on the same jsp page but i am not able to display it as  stacked bar chart. 
Here is my jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,javax.*" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="com.rajesh.action.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>January</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Report for January</h1>

<body>
<table border="1" >
<tr>
<th>Market</th>
<th>Jan-01</th>
<th>Jan-02</th>
<th>Jan-03</th>
<th>Jan-04</th>
<th>Jan-05</th>
<th>Jan-06</th>
<th>Jan-07</>
<th>Jan-08</>
<th>Jan-09</>
<th>Jan-10</>
<th>Jan-11</>
<th>Jan-12</>
<th>Jan-13</>
<th>Jan-14</>
<th>Jan-15</>
<th>Jan-16</>
<th>Jan-17</>
<th>Jan-18</>
<th>Jan-19</>
<th>Jan-20</>
<th>Jan-21</>
<th>Jan-22</>
<th>Jan-23</>
<th>Jan-24</>
<th>Jan-25</>
<th>Jan-26</>
<th>Jan-27</>
<th>Jan-28</>
<th>Jan-29</>
<th>Jan-30</>
<th>Jan-31</>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">AUK</>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">AUS</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">ADE</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Ebay</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>


<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Play</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/excanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<link href="plugins/jquery.jqplot.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="plugins/jquery.jqplot.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<body>

<span id="info3">Nothing yet.</span>
<div id="chart3" style="height:900px;width:1300px; "></div>



<c:forEach var="temp" items="${abc}">
s1.push('${item.count}');
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="temp" items="${abc}">
s2.push('${item.dataamount}');
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="temp" items="${abc}">
s3.push('${item.result}');
</c:forEach>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var s1 = [];
var s2 = [];
var s3 = [];

var axisDates = ["Jan 1", "Jan 2", "Jan 3","Jan 4","Jan 5","Jan 6","Jan 7","Jan  8","Jan 9","Jan 10","Jan 11","Jan 12","Jan 13","Jan 14","Jan 15","Jan 16","Jan 17","Jan  18","Jan 19","Jan 20","Jan 21","Jan 22","Jan 23","Jan 24","Jan 25","Jan 26","Jan  27","Jan28","Jan 29","Jan 30","Jan 31"]


plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {

stackSeries: true,
varyBarColor: true,


captureRightClick: true,

animate : !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
seriesDefaults : {
renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
rendererOptions: {
barPadding : 20, 


barMargin : 25, 

barDirection : 'vertical',
barWidth : 30,

shadowOffset : 4,
highlightMouseOver: true   
}, 
pointLabels: {show: true}
},
axes: {xaxis: {
renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, ticks: axisDates

},
yaxis: {min:0, max: 2300

}
},

legend: {
show: true,
location: 'e',
placement: 'outside'
}     
});
  // Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
  // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
  // clicked along with the data for that point.
$('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
$('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
}
);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You still need help here (bounty)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var s1 = [3.42, 3.68, 3.64, 3.76, 3.75, 3.54,4.14,3.95, 3.84, 4.04, 4.29, 4.19,4.09,3.77, 4.82, 4.49, 4.42, 4.85,3.98, 3.97,4.19, 4.12, 4.09, 4.16, 4.38, 4.33, 4.43, 4.03, 4.25, 3.86, 4.16];
var s3 = [1200.48, 1604.94, 1431.20, 1335.72, 1266.45, 1308.25, 1698.32, 1464.18, 1461.53, 1502.08, 1369.72,1316.11, 1260.54, 1535.39, 1925.02, 1890.05, 1658.61, 1560.57,1574.59, 1682.91, 2025.93, 2019, 1645.09, 1801.57, 1812.67, 1818.51, 2130.70, 1803.06, 1926.22, 1630.69, 1570.69];
var s2 = [351, 436, 393, 355,338,370,410,371, 381, 372, 319,314,308,407,399, 421, 375, 322,396,424,483,490, 402, 433, 414,420,481,447,453,422,378];
var axisDates = ["Jan 1", "Jan 2", "Jan 3","Jan 4","Jan 5","Jan 6","Jan 7",
"Jan 8","Jan 9","Jan 10","Jan 11","Jan 12","Jan 13","Jan 14","Jan 15","Jan 16","Jan 17","Jan 18","Jan 19","Jan 20","Jan 21","Jan 22","Jan 23","Jan 24","Jan 25","Jan 26","Jan 27","Jan28","Jan 29","Jan 30","Jan 31"]

plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {

stackSeries: true,
varyBarColor: true,


captureRightClick: true,
```